# Editing blogger theme, can't find the HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I need to change the CSS values of `li` elements of the pages section of a blog (in the nav bar), but blogger theme has different XML syntax, this corresponds to 3 `li` elements:

[image]

```
  <b:widget-setting name='pageListJson'><![CDATA[{'home': {'href': 'https://blog.blogspot.com/', 'title': 'Home', 'position': 0}, '111111': {'href': 'https://blog.blogspot.com/p/blog-page.html', 'title': 'Page1', 'position': 1}, '222222': {'href': 'https://blog.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_3.html', 'title': 'Page2', 'position': 2}}]]></b:widget-setting>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your blog in an internet browser, right click the menu, and click "Inspect Element".

The will reveal what the HTML looks like.

Comment: What is available to me is the code in the question, not HTML, I want to change the theme style

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the "Menu item", then "Inspect Element" now you can see the CSS code of the Menu item you want to change at the bottom right.